# Remainders of powers of 10 when divided by prime

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

While doing a number theory question, I observed that the repeating digits of decimal expansions of $\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac{6}{7}$ form a pattern. They are $142857,285714,428571,571428,714285,857142$. I wondered if there is a link between these and the fact that all of them represent the same permutation $(142857)$. Then, while trying to see how is that happening, I came upon the fact that $$\frac{10}{7}=10\times\frac{1}{7}$$
$$=1.428571...$$
and this is how we get the pattern for repeating values of $\frac{3}{7}$. Similarly, considering $\frac{100}{7},\frac{1000}{7},\frac{10000}{7},\frac{100000}{7}$ gives us the pattern for other four fractions. From $\frac{10^6}{7}$ onwards, the pattern starts repeating because of Fermat's little theorem, since,
$$10^{k+6}\equiv 10^{k}\pmod 7$$

The question finally reduces to:
**Why do powers of 10 give distinct remainders upto $10^6$? Is this property satisfied by all primes other than $2$ and $5$?**

Is this somehow related to the fact that $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field?

Please help.

Comment: See [Full reptend prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_reptend_prime)

Comment: you're getting distinct remainders because $10\equiv 3$ is a [primitive root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive+root+of+7) of $7$

Comment: I know neither Full reptend prime nor primitive root of $7$, isn't there any elementary proof of this fact. Say, we assume $10^k\equiv 10^l\pmod 7$ for some $0<k<l<7$ and then there arises some contradiction.

Comment: $$10^k\equiv 10^l \Rightarrow 10^{k-l}\equiv 1 \Rightarrow (k-l)\mid 6$$

That says $k-l$ has to be a divisor of $6$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works because $7$ is a factor of $10^{(7-1)}-1=10^6-1=999999$. We have that the period of the decimal expansion of $7$ will be a factor of $6$.

If we look at $999999=3^3\cdot 7\cdot 11 \cdot 13\cdot 37$ we find that

$3$ and $9$ are factors of $10^1-1=9$ and have period $1$

$11$ is a factor of $10^2-1=99$ and has period $2$ ($9$ we already know has period $1$)

$27$ and $37$ are factors of $10^3-1=999$ and have period $3$

$7$ and $13$ are factors of $10^6-1=999999$ not already considered, and have period $6$

---

First note that for any number there are only a finite number of possible remainders. If we exclude prime factors of $2$ and $5$ (these shift the decimal point rather than affecting the ultimate periodicity), a number $n$ will never divide $10^r$ without remainder. If you work through the calculation you will see that as soon as a remainder repeats, the calculation repeats and the decimal repeats.

Suppose you divide through and have a repeated remainder: $10^a=ns+r, 10^b=nt+r, b\gt a$, then subtracting these gives $10^b-10^a=n(t-s)=10^a\left(10^{b-a}-1\right)$ and $n$ is a factor of $10^{b-a}-1$. So the decimal repeats after $m$ digits precisely when $n$ is a factor of $10^m-1$ (it has no factors in common with $10^a$). If $m$ is the smallest positive integer for which this happens this is the shortest period over which the decimal (and the remainder) repeats.

Since we have completely factored $10^6-1$ we have identified all the possible numbers with period dividing $6$, including periods $1$, $2$ and $3$. The only other numbers which repeat with a period less than $6$ are found by factoring

$9999=9\times 11\times 101$ which gives $101$ and factors which contain it period $4$

$99999=9\times 41 \times 271$ with $41$ and $271$ and factors which contain them having period $5$

Other integers have longer periods and will therefore have no repetition of remainders in the first six.

---

There are plenty of interesting facts to explore, including precisely what does happen for $\frac 1n$ when $n$ has factors $2$ and/or $5$ and what happens in bases other than the arbitrary base $10$.

I am hoping that the examples here will prompt you to check that the periods are as advertised, and to explore a bit more what is going on.